# Extract username from XML in Mule 4 (not Mule 3) using XPATH or DataWeave

Tags: xml, xpath, dataweave, mule4

Below is the sample xml screenshot, I need to extract user name and password using XPATH. Please Help.

[xml screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B45O0.jpg)

Comment: Never use screenshots for code or XML.   Use text because it's easier to search and copy-and-paste.

Comment: Also, you're expected to provide your attempt and an explanation of what you get and how it differs from what you want.

Comment: Why not use data-weave directly just type ` `output application/java ---payload.Evenlope.Header.authentication.password` to get the password value and the same for the username.

Comment: @kjhughes, It is not duplicate. Am looking for changes unsing Mule 4 not Mule 3. Thanks

Comment: @VinnyChinn: I've reopened.  Please address my comment regarding images vs text .  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly in DataWeave

```
output application/java 
---
payload.Evenlope.Header.authentication.password
```

to get the password value and the same for the username.